# Waf Application already defines some members (initializecomponent, main, _contentLoaded)

Tags: c#, wpf, waf-framework-c#

I'm using the WAF-Framework for building a MVVM-Application. I got my own App-Class (App.xaml and App.xaml.cs).

Everytime I try to compile my application I get 3 different error messages:

1. The type `MyApplication.Presentation.App` already defines a member
   `InitializeComponent` with same types of parameters
2. The type `MyApplication.Presentation.App` already defines a member `Main` with same types of parameters
3. The type `MyApplication.Presentation.App` already contains a definition for `_contentLoaded`

When I click on the error-message I get redirected to a file called **App.g.cs**. If I then remove everything within this file, my application will be build and everthings works as wished. But after another change the file is back and I would have to delete it again.

I checked all my files and I can't find another definition of these 3 members. I don't have another Main-Method anywhere. I also tried to rename my Application but this didn't solve the problem.

Any suggestions what I could do to solve this annoying problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had something very similar recently, and it turned out that when importing existing code files I had imported the `obj` directory itself!
[image: screen shot of visual studio]

This directory contained, for example, the auto-generated (and automatically imported) `MainWindow.g.i.cs` file. So I was effectively including the same partial class definition twice, hence the "already defined" errors.

Excluding this folder from the project and rebuilding the solution works to resolve the errors.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else had similar problem - this was my solution:

The problem occured after I've copied and pasted one of my Views (.xaml and .cs files). I changed the file's name, BUT NOT A CLASS NAME, so I had two classes with same name.
Then after other changes in code I forgot about it.
This was giving same error as in question.

So like in previous answer the compiler while auto-generating g.cs and g.i.cs files was giving an error - because there was this class name used already. A class was partial (as xaml views are), so duplicated classname was not a problem, but duplicated constructors and everything else - was.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly with Ursula, i'had done similar but not same thing. The thing I've done was;

1. I wanted to move my styles from App.xaml to another place to manage and find easier
2. First i've created new Resourse Dictionary
3. Then moved the styles to new one.
4. name spaces were missing in xaml file so i copied everything in the App.xaml. And also it copied `x:Class="SomeApplicationName.App" too`
5. After removing that line. Problem had been solved :-)